# Asus ROG with Ubuntu disable iRST

Tags: boot, kernel, rst

I had Ubuntu installed on my ROG for quite some time - a year give or take. I have not been using it daily but I used it for experimenting with running a local server and general development.

Quite recently as I boot my ROG, I get the Republic of Gamers screen without seeing Ubuntu logo at the bottom. The laptop failed to get past that screen.

My primary guess was to insert an Ubuntu 20.04 USB and try to see what's wrong. When I got to the installation screen, it told me I had to disable RST which is strange as I would assume it would stay disabled - it can't just suddenly enable itself can it?!

So my question is - how do you disable iRST if there are no options in BIOS to disable it and I don't have access to the Windows install (that's long gone).

Is there a way to disable it through the terminal on Ubuntu?

**Update:**

I've switched to a different Boot Option and got as far as seeing

```
error: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-55-generic has invalid signature.
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: If there was a firmware (UEFI) update it can be re-enabled.

Comment: Under Security, I've disabled Secure Boot & under Boot I've enabled Launch CSM and Launch PXE OpROM policy which said "Controls the execution of UEFI and Legacy PXE OpRom"

Comment: I'm now getting a different message: end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block

Comment: Yes, disable Secure Boot. No, do not enable CSM (either isn't needed - OS properly installed in UEFI mode - or it can screw the boot order) nor PXE (network boot). **Disable Intel RST** like it supposedly was before.

Comment: Just tried that, getting the same error - not synching: VFS...

Comment: *Unable to mount root fs* means it couldn't find the root partition. With Intel RST or "RAID" modes that would be understandable. Supposedly in order to install Ubuntu the first time you changed the mode to AHCI? You need to assure the same settings are in use.

Comment: Changed SATA to AHCI and then had to choose a different kernel - worked out in the end. Thanks @ChanganAuto. Do you want to post the answer in case others face a similar issue?